# UITableView accumulates tens of cells after row insertions/updates from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In our app we have a controller that manages a UITableView (NOT a UITableViewController in this case). This controller is both the table view's delegate and data source. It is also the NSFetchedResultsController's (hereafter FRC) delegate. We register a custom nib with a consistent reuse identifier for our table view cells. After reloading 8 cells several times, we see about 40 UITableViewCells inside the UITableView (UITableViewWrapperView, technically speaking) on the View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy screen.

Why might UITableView not be removing cells from its view hierarchy? This unfortunately presents a huge performance issue after a few batches of the aforementioned updates where scrolling on the UITableView lags very noticeably.

**Our FRC->UITableView code:**

didChangeObject:

```
        switch type {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            sectionsToReload.addIndex(newIndexPath!.section)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            sectionsToReload.addIndex(indexPath!.section)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            sectionsToReload.addIndex(indexPath!.section)
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Move:
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            sectionsToReload.addIndex(indexPath!.section)
            sectionsToReload.addIndex(newIndexPath!.section)
        }
```

didChangeSection:

```
    let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex)
    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.insertedSections.addIndexes(indexSet)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        self.deletedSections.addIndexes(indexSet)
    default:
        return
    }
```

controllerWillChangeContent:

```
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.insertedSections = NSMutableIndexSet()
    self.deletedSections = NSMutableIndexSet()
    self.sectionsToReload = NSMutableIndexSet()
```

controllerDidChangeContent:

```
    for section in self.insertedSections {
        if self.sectionsToReload.containsIndex(section) {
            self.sectionsToReload.removeIndex(section)
        }
    }
    for section in self.deletedSections {
        if self.sectionsToReload.containsIndex(section) {
            self.sectionsToReload.removeIndex(section)
        }
    }

    if shouldReloadSectionsWhenRowsChange {
        self.tableView.reloadSections(self.sectionsToReload, withRowAnimation: .None)
    }

    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**UITableViewDataSource methods**

```
public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections {
        return sections[section].numberOfObjects
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

public override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections {
        return sections.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

public override func getCount() -> Int {
    if let count = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count {
        return count
    }
    return 0
}

public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellNibIdentifier) else {
        Rlog.e(self, "Failed to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:\(cellNibIdentifier)")
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    self.configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```